# How to load resnet_v1_50 checkpoint into tf.keras ResNet50 model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, resnet

I have a .ckpt file that contains the weights of a model based on tensorflow v1 `resnet_v1_50`. I tried to inspect the checkpoint file using the function `tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint.print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file` and the output is like:

```
video_model/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/beta (DT_FLOAT) [64]
video_model/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/beta/Adam (DT_FLOAT) [64]
video_model/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/beta/Adam_1 (DT_FLOAT) [64]
video_model/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma (DT_FLOAT) [64]
video_model/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam (DT_FLOAT) [64]
video_model/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma/Adam_1 (DT_FLOAT) [64]
video_model/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_mean (DT_FLOAT) [64]
video_model/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_variance (DT_FLOAT) [64]
[...]
```

What I want to do is to load this variable (or a subset of them) into [tf.keras ResNet50](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/ResNet50) model as all the other layers in my model are written in keras; The structure of the two architectures should be the same, but if I inspect a compiled version of keras ResNet50 here's what I obtain:

```
[...]
layer_with_weights-0/bias/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE (DT_FLOAT) [64]
layer_with_weights-0/kernel/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE (DT_FLOAT) [7,7,3,64]
layer_with_weights-1/beta/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE (DT_FLOAT) [64]
layer_with_weights-1/gamma/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE (DT_FLOAT) [64]
layer_with_weights-1/moving_mean/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE (DT_FLOAT) [64]
layer_with_weights-1/moving_variance/.ATTRIBUTES/VARIABLE_VALUE (DT_FLOAT) [64]
[...]
```

I think that it's just a re-naming of the layers. Is there any chance I can do that and reuse the pretrained checkpoint?

Comment: Did you find out a way to do this?

Comment: I did not, unfortunately. I opted to load checkpoint into a resnet_v1_50 model and run an evaluation in a different session (so without training). Then, because of poor results, I changed model and moved to other approaches :/